# Concentration inequity with Random Gaussian Matrix

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, probability-limit-theorems, concentration-of-measure

The rows of $X_{n\times p}$  are $\it{i.i.d}\:\:\: p$ variate Gaussian vectors with distribution $\mathcal{N}_p(0,\Omega)$. Let $\varepsilon$ be another $n$-variate normal random variable independent of $X$ having distribution $\mathcal{N}_n(0,\Sigma)$. Then for any fixed $u \in \mathbb{R}^p$ with $\|u\|_2=1 $, can we upperbound
$$ P\left(\left|\frac{\varepsilon'Xu}{n}\right|> \eta\right)$$

by exponentially small expression (in terms of $n, p, \lambda_{\max}(\Sigma)$ and $\lambda_{\max}(\Omega)$)?

I am aware of Hanson-Wright type concentration inequalities but I have not seen one with product of two Gaussian inner-product. If I get some suggested readings/paper that will be helpful as well and thanks in advance.

Comment: Any progress on this one?